# How to execute a script that containts a window.onload after it is injected into an iframe that lives on the same page

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, onload

I am wondering how I can get a script that is inserted into an iframe to execute that contains a window.onload function. Because the iframe is already loaded, when I insert the script it is not executed. I do not want to manipulate the script that is inserted in any way. Is there anyway to either re-create the onload state of the iframe without losing the newly inserted script, or, is there a way to have the script saved into the iframe's DOM so that it loads when it is refreshed?

You can see the code at http://www.fundifi.com/victor/pixel_sandbox/sandbox.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have any other scripts listening to the window's load event, you could try to re-fire the load event:

```
$(window).trigger('load');
```

If you can't run that code from within the iframe, you can try to look for the iframe window from the parent (provided there are no cross-domain issues):

```
var iframeWindow = $('iframe#my-frame').get(0).contentWindow;
$(iframeWindow).trigger('load');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the bottom version and it worked. I didn't try the top one because I don't know how that would know when exactly to trigger. Could you kindly explain what the get(0) does?

Comment: The get(0) gets the native DOM element out of the jQuery result set. That entire statement could just be `document.getElementById('my-frame').contentWindow;` if you prefer.